# Sparse matrix array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matrix

I have m square matricies of dimension n. I keep all these matricies in an array like that

```
mybasis = zeros(n,n,m)
```

Whenever I want to do something with these matricies I can simply use one for loop with:

```
for i=1:m
    B=myBasis(:,:,i);
    %do something with B
end
```

Now I have m square sparse matricies. I would like to save all my matricies as a sparse matrix in an array, so that I can easily iterate through them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather store the sparse Matrixes in a cell array:

```
mybasis=cell(1,m)
for i=1:m
    myBasis(i)=sparse(n,n)
end


for i=1:m
    B=myBasis(i);
    %do something with B
end
```

Comment: You mean myBasis(i)=sparse(zeros(n,n))?

Comment: My fault, sure. Actually its sufficient to write `sparse(n,n)`